# How do i set the path to my font-awesome.min.css file

Tags: html, font-awesome

I'm trying to include font awesome into my web page. I downloaded the font awesome 4.7.0 but i don't know how to set the link to font-awesome.min.css file, I need help please, thanks!

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` place that in the `<head>....</head>`

Answer (score 0):

Put the following `<link>` tag inside of your `<head></head>` tags, like this:

`<head>`
    `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
`</head>`